# JMeter Variable Value Getting Lost In Same ThreadGroup And Simple Controller

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing

I am using Jmeter to create a scenario for load testing. The format is like following.

```
1.Thread Group  
 1.1.Simple Controller  
  1.1.1 HTTP request 1---extract a certain variable X from the response  
  1.1.2.HTTP request 2( Send X as a parameter)  
  1.1.3 Simple Controller  
   1.1.3.1. HTTP request [Try to use X as parameter]
```

I am running it with only 1 thread, directly from Jmeter.

**Problem: the value of the variable X becomes blank at 1.1.3.1.**

Sometimes, even at the same level also the variable value seems lost in the next event. i.e. if there are two consecutive HTTP requests, in the second request the value is lost.

**My question is: Why the value is getting lost and what is the solution to prevent it from being lost?**

The way I have used before is like reorganizing the events. But it may not be possible all the time. Is there any way to retain the value through some global variable?

Comment: Have you tried using debug sampler ? Can you share your script file? Technically there should not be any issue while sharing variable between different controllers (under same thread group)

Comment: Try passing other variables into second controller request. There must be some other issue. Or if you can share script then I can look into it.

Comment: Thanks Arif. I do use Debug Sampler. Debug Sampler  placed between 1.1.1 and 1.1.2 shows correct value but Debug Sampler  placed between 1.1.3 and 1.1.3.1 shows blank value. Sorry I cant share the script, as I am not allowed to share code.

Comment: Thats strange because the same works perfectly fine for me. As I suggested earlier, you can try passing some other variable (from user defined variables perhaps) in second controller and see if that works!. I believe issue is with something else.

Comment: I accept  that the behavior is weird. But I can replicate the scenario in many cases, including following. 1.Thread Group
1.1.Simple Controller 1
1.1.1 HTTP request 1---extract a certain variable X from the response
1.2.Debug Sampler 1
1.3 Simple Controller
1.3.1. HTTP request --use value of X [Works perfectly]                            1.4 Debug Sampler 2------------Value Of X is Null

Comment: Can you create a new script for experiment. With just two controllers and two requests. It will be helpful in tracing the issue.

Comment: Thanks Arif for your reply. I have edited my question, adding the scenario. I think value of variable is getting lost when multiple controllers are involved with their own http requests.

Comment: So you get the problem when you use controller inside another controller?

Comment: Hi Arif, I tried to pinpoint the problem. Now I have 2 different Http req within 1 single controller. In first req I extract the value from response. In 2nd Req I use it successfully. After the 2nd Http Req, I have placed a Debug Sampler. The value of the extracted variable becomes null.

Comment: Sorry Please ignore the previous comment, there was a mistake. But I think when there are 2 controllers involved, something is going wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I have found the problem case and one solution.

According to the scenario I tested, if there is a controller within another controller, the value of variable gets lost.

i.e. in the format mentioned in the question, the value will be lost. The format can be restructured as below.

- 1.Thread Group
- 1.1 Simple Controller 1
- 1.1.1 HTTP request 1---extract a certain variable X from the response
- 1.2 Simple Controller 2
- 1.2.1.HTTP request 2( Send X as a parameter)
- 1.2.2. HTTP request 3 [Try to use X as parameter]--Works Perfectly This Way

Comment: How does this address the case where the outer controller needs to be a loop?